# What differentiates an abstract noun with a concrete noun?

Tags: terminology

Is *sunlight* a concrete or abstract noun?

What differentiates an abstract noun with a concrete noun?

Comment: Is "vacuum" (as in "perfect vacuum") a concrete noun? What about "light"?

Comment: @Joachim i don't know!

Comment: Can you explain what are you exactly asking? Because, maybe it's me, but in its current form, it seems more like a question about physics rather than English... :)

Comment: I've never heard of this distinction, but I'm not a native speaker and [Wikipedia knows it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Concrete_nouns_and_abstract_nouns). According to Wikipedia anything that represents a physical entity is a concrete noun. I don't think that this necessarily imply mass, as "sunlight" would be concrete according to this definition.

Comment: @Alenanno The classification of different types of nouns is something about grammar.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's not really about grammar. It's an attempt by some guy writing in Wikipedia to divide up the world in a particular way, and reflect this in his lexical analysis and termonology. If it's *about* anything, I'd say it's about epistemology (the study of knowledge, and how we come to know it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't read about abstract nouns on Wikipedia; I have read about them in a grammar book, and at the time I have studied English at high school, the teacher introduced those terms.

Comment: I think you're tying yourself in pointless knots. If physicists suddenly discover a change in the nature of light, do you think that this discovery is somehow going to spontaneously bring about a linguistic change? If your categorisation is not based on linguistic phenomena, then why care?

Comment: The problem I see with this question is that is not specific to English: When studying Italian at school, I was given the same noun classification I was given when I studied English. A _proper noun_ is not different from a _nome proprio_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Well I'm with Neil on this one. Abstract/concrete are sometimes useful concepts for very broad classification of nouns. But they don't embody anything absolute about the real world, and it's pointless trying to decide on whether marginal cases should be classified as one or the other. We just end up philosophising - there's nothing particularly involving *English Language* as generally understood here at EL&U.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't say I was not with Neil Coffey; as a matter of fact, I voted his comment. I would say this question is off-topic because it seems to ask an opinion, and there isn't a concrete problem to resolve; plus, it doesn't seem to ever help any future visitors.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'm going to upvote your answer because I think that's as far as you can go with the distinction (OP's first question). I think OP's second question is about as useful as *"how many angels can dance on the head of a pin?"*. So I'd much prefer the second to be edited out, but I won't vote to close because I see nothing wrong with the question you answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *concrete noun* names something you can perceive with your senses; an *abstract noun* names something you cannot perceive with your senses.

Examples of concrete nouns are: *table*, *noise*, *pineapple*.
Examples of abstract nouns are: *democracy*, *belief*, *sadness*.

<sub>**[Reference: *English Grammar*—David Daniels, Barbara Daniels; ISBN 0-006-467109-7]**</sub>

Comment: And according to the authors, what's the *linguistic* basis for this categorisation...?

Comment: And: what *effect* does this categorization have? Are concrete nouns used *any* different from abstract ones? Do they obey different rules?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: I think the *concrete/abstract nouns* distinction was part of primitive early attempts to codify "semantics" as a formal discipline. The idea being that *concretes* had a 1-to-1 relationship with pre-existing things, so they were "just" symbols. Whereas *abstracts* denoted things that didn't "really" exist, so in a sense the word defines/crystalises/creates its real-world referent. A bit facile by today's standards, I think.

Comment: @Joachim they obviously do, what else do you think is the reason for subclassing them? do you mean to say linguists of the century are doing things for no reason?

Comment: @Pacerier: I wasn't *saying* anything, I was asking. Whenever something is divided in categories I expect there to be some *reason* or *effect* from that categorization. *How* is a concrete noun treated differently from an abstract one?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Regarding *"a bit facile by today's standards"*, I'd beg to differ. There seems to be usages in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_linguistics

Comment: @kiamlaluno, So is "dance" an abstract or concrete noun? What you perceive with your sense are the "movements and steps", but isn't "dance" abstract just like "democracy"?

Comment: @Pacerier You see people dancing, not the dance. So it's abstract like _democracy_.

Comment: @Pacerier: None of the words ***concrete, abstract, real, noun*** occur there, and I'm not going to wade through the entire article to see where it contradicts something I said nearly 4 years ago. How does it imply I'm wrong to say that *concrete/abstract noun* isn't a very important distinction for linguists today?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't quite get you since I've already said that in the previous comment: There seems to be usages in computational linguistics, so the distinction is important in some ways.

Comment: It's relevant because small children are first taught that nouns are words for objects, things you can see; then later they are taught that not all nouns are things you can see. It's one of several categories or schemas that are used with children but may have less value for adults.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are best asking this question of the person who first taught you this terminology. It's not an official term like noun or verb. That said, some words clearly describe actual things you can touch, hear, and see (desk, dog, apple) and others describe intangible concepts (love, employment contract, marriage, tax rate). When my kids and I play 20 Questions, we add a category that covers these things along with TV shows, songs, emotions and other intangibles. Definitely for advanced players :-).

In Object Oriented Programming, concrete classes describe things that can actually exist (truck, employee, purchase order, savings account, square) and abstract classes describe "umbrella concepts" that are more category than object (vehicle, business entity, transaction, bank account, shape). I ask my students to imagine opening "just a bank account - not a savings account, not a chequing account, not a retirement account, just an account." It can't be done. Abstract classes can't be instantiated. Only concrete ones can. Now, does this have anything to do with the distinction someone made to you? And how does sunlight fit into this?

Comment: *Abstract* and *concrete*, in the sense that the second paragraph of this answer is about are **relative** concepts: *savings account* is concrete relative to *bank account* but abstract relative to *savings account paying interest at the annual rate of 1.5%*, which in turn is abstract relative to *my savings account*.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns can all be catagorized as concrete or abstract.  It is a linguistic construct.  Concrete nouns can be sensed, or more simply put have atomic structure or form.  However, language is complex and variable so a specific song or dance is considered concrete due to its specific pattern of tones or movements, whereas time, despite its patterns, is considered abstract.  Abstract nouns are typically emotions, philosophies, ideas, or concepts.

Comment: What about 'angel?

Answer (score 0):

'Concrete nouns can be perceived by our senses'.

This cannot be correct. Our senses do not perceive the noun 'corn'. Our senses perceive corn -- that entity to which the noun 'corn' refers. (Or to the extent that our *sense of language* perceives nouns, it perceives all nouns.)

When I was taught this concrete/abstract distinction in middle school, at that time I thought this was foolish for counterexamples came to mind immediately. 'Electron' is an entity that cannot be (so to speak) 'sensed', but it is not (so to speak) an 'idea'.

I did not have the words to describe my attitude at the time, but now I describe it this way: The books (and teachers) were, no doubt unwittingly, trying to teach us a (dubious) ontology under the guise of teaching us grammar.

If you can show me how nouns that refer to things that can be 'perceived by the senses' have some unique morphological features (say), or some other properties that control *how they are used in a sentence,* then I will accept them as valid grammatical categories. Otherwise the distinction makes no more sense than distinguishing 'fooish' nouns as nouns that refer to round things, and 'barish' as nouns that are not 'fooish'.

Thus 'apple' is a fooish noun, while 'banana' is a barish noun.

These might be useful categories for a fruit packing factory, and might be of pragmatic interest to those programming a natural language interface for use in a packing factory, but they make no linguistic sense.

I may certainly be wrong, and would love to be corrected if I am.

[Edited to add:]

I will somewhat correct my previous claim. A noun might be *abstract* if it affords a certain kind of morphology suggested my these examples:

'paradigm' -> 'paradigmatic', and
'universe' -> 'universal'.

In contrast, paradigmatic concrete nouns like 'corn' and 'rock' (and the original poster's 'sunlight') afford no such morphological change.

This, though, is a fairly arcane distinction to teach middle school students.

Answer (score -1):

Abstract nouns are basically used for representation of ideas, qualities, states, something that cannot be perceived by the senses of touch, sight, hearing, smell and taste. For example, honesty, happiness, sadness are abstract nouns.
Concrete nouns, on the other hand, can be perceived by our five senses. Mostly, the concrete nouns refer to something that we can touch and so they are also named as material nouns. For example, noise, sunlight (in your case), table, chair, etc.
I hope that helped.