# How to check what type a noun is

Tags: nouns, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we check if a noun is concrete or abstract?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-we-check-if-a-noun-is-concrete-or-abstract)

Is there any resource or online dictionary to check the type of noun? For example: I want to check if *Room*, *House*, *Office*, *Brain*, etc., are abstract or concrete nouns. Is there any way to simply know without posting a question here each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guide to recognising the difference between abstract and concrete nouns:

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/abstractnoun.htm

The examples you give ("Room, House, Office, Brain") are all concrete nouns, since they can all be detected with one of your five senses.